# Python turtle program not drawing polygon properly

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

When I run the program using the turtle tool, it just makes one horizontal line and does not make a complete shape. I am not sure why this is happening. I have already made a working program that would draw a predetermined shape such as a square. I have already tested my computations and I believe my for-loop is correct. Am I making just some silly syntax error?

```
# polygon program

# get inputs
side_count = int(input( "How many sides does the polygon have?" ))
side_length = int(input( "How long is each side?" ))

# compute side angle
shape_angle = (side_count - 2) * 180

# import turtle modules
from turtle import *

# measure angles in
degrees()

# drawing speed
speed( 6 )

# square specs
color( 'green' )
width( 3 )
setheading( 0 )

# forloop to draw the polygon
for side in range ( side_count ):
    forward ( side_length ) 
    left ( shape_angle )

# all done drawing
done()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I agree with @TudorPopescu that this line is your primary issue:

```
shape_angle = (side_count - 2) * 180
```

That solution doesn't work for me, so I suggest something simpler to start:

```
shape_angle = 360 / side_count
```

Your code reworked with the above fix and style changes:

```
# polygon program

# import turtle modules
from turtle import *

# get inputs
side_count = int(input("How many sides does the polygon have? "))
side_length = int(input("How long is each side? "))

# compute side angle
shape_angle = 360 / side_count

# measure angles in
degrees()  # the default

# drawing speed
speed('normal')  # the default

# square specs
color('green')
width(3)
setheading(0)  # the default initial heading

# for loop to draw the polygon
for side in range(side_count):
    forward(side_length)
    left(shape_angle)

# all done drawing
done()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, import all your modules first, its not necessary until you have to use it, but it's a good habit. Also the `shape_angle` is the total of the whole shape.
To make it work you would have your original code:

`shape_angle = (side_count - 2) * 180`

Then put it in brackets and divide it by `side_count` to find the individual angle, the result:

`shape_angle = ((side_count - 2) * 180) / side_count`

Also get rid of the `degrees`

```
import turtle as *
side_count = int(input( "How many sides does the polygon have?" ))
side_length = int(input( "How long is each side?" ))
shape_angle = ((side_count - 2) * 180) / side_count
speed( 6 )
color( 'green' )
width( 3 )
setheading( 0 )
for side in range ( side_count ):
    forward ( side_length ) 
    left ( shape_angle )
done()
```

`

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't actually test your "solution" to the problem as the `import turtle as *` doesn't work but should be `from turtle import *`.  Also, it doesn't draw things I would call interesting -- i.e. input of 5 sides doesn't draw a pentagon, etc.